# Supervisor forgets to cover shift

Tags: communication

I clean an early childcare center. I work Saturdays and Sundays for over two yrs. Always coming in when asked never saying no.

I asked for a Sunday off 2 weeks in advance in a text message. My supervisor said "yes you can have the day off." I took the Sunday off and on Monday received a call from the director telling me I was fired for not showing for my shift and that it was UNACCEPTABLE. The centre didn't get cleaned for Monday school. I said "I asked for the day and was given permission" and I had proof. I screen shot the conversation and sent it to her.

I had came to the director complaining of mistreatment by my supervisor. When she got back to me, her apology was shallow and told me nothing had changed with my schedule. She had a talk with my supervisor and he's not being fired. It was unacceptable when it was me but was acceptable from him. Why is that?

Comment: You're not really asking us why. You already know why. It's unfair. Look for another job. Look for a new employer that respects you.

Comment: You asked for the day off 2 weeks in advance and received permission to take it off. As the date approached, I assume that you were still shown on the schedule for that day and no one was scheduled to replace you. If that was the case, It seems to me that that you share some of the responsibility for not bringing it to the attention of your supervisor.

Comment: By "share some of the responsibility", I don't mean you should be punished, but that even though you had permission to take the day off, if you knew, ahead of time, that no one was scheduled to cover your shift, you could have avoided the whole situation by speaking up.

Answer (score 24):

Not all mistakes or errors in judgement at work are firing offenses.

What they thought you did - *just don't show up one day, with no notice and without permission* - is really bad. They would fire you for it. Once you were able to show you didn't do that, they didn't fire you after all.

What your supervisor did - *forgot someone asked for time off, didn't arrange cover, and caused upset to you by the director telling you that you were fired* - is not good, but it's not a firing offense. Well, it might be at some employers but you can tell it isn't at yours, because your supervisor wasn't fired. I think you can see it is a different kind of mistake.

You can decide whether to forgive your employer for their original reaction to what they thought was happening. I probably would. Not showing up without permission or notice is a pretty bad offense. You can decide whether to forgive your employer for the weak apology. I might or might not. If you decide not to, start looking for another job, but don't quit until you find one.

It's not clear from your question what needs to change with your schedule, but if there is something you want, now might be a good time to ask for it. They may feel a little guilty over temporarily firing you and speaking so strongly to you when they thought you had done something you hadn't.

Comment: It's true that a no-call-no-show is really bad, but if the OP has worked there for over two years without incident, a decent workplace would at least ask the OP what happened before jumping straight to firing him/her. There are many possible mitigating circumstances.

Comment: no argument there. A strong apology, including a phrase like "I should have known you would never do something like that" is the least the OP should expect. Is not getting one a deal breaker? Only the OP can decide.

Answer (score 6):

The director came in and the school was dirty and over reacted. She should have consulted with your supervisor and at least asked you what happened.

By the time she talked to your supervisor she had cooled off a bit. And she may feel it would be easier to replace you than your supervisor.

A shallow apology is better than no apology.

Only you can decide if you want to find another job.